# Delphi, how to free record in TList

Tags: delphi

I want to know the best way to **free a TList filled with record**.

I have the following record:

```
type
TPkBill = record
    PkBill: integer;
    Constructor Create(c_PkBill: integer);

constructor TPkBill.Create(c_PkBill: integer);
begin
    PkBill := c_PkBill;
end;
```

I create the list and  fill it with the record:

```
procedure TfrmProject.lvBillDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var   
   i, iCount: integer;
   item: TListItem;
   oPkBill: TPkBill;
   lstPkBill: Tlist;
begin
   iCount := 0;
   lstPkBill:= TList.Create;

   //if an item is selected in lv
   if (lvBill.ItemIndex = -1) then begin exit; end
   else
   begin
        //Loop through all items and get selected item
        for i := 0 to lvBill.Items.Count - 1 do
        begin
            item := lvBill.Items.Item[i];
            if(item.Selected = true)then
            begin
                //create new item
                oPkBill := TPkBill.Create(StrToInt(lvBill.Items[i].Caption));
                //add it to a list
                lstPkBill.Add(TObject(oPkBill)); 
                //add up
                iCount := iCount +1;      
            end;
        end;
        //Now we have a list ok pkBill

        if(iCount > 1)then //other stuff I do
    end
```

I want to be able to free the TList and also to free the record.

Here is what I already tried:

```
for i := 0 to lstPkBill.Count - 1 do
begin
    //TObject(TPkBill(lstPkBill[i])).Free;  //Acces violation at adress..
    //FreeMem(TPkBill(lstPkBill[i]));   //Incompatible types
    //FreeMem(TObject(lstPkBill[i]));   //Incompatible types
end;
lstPkBill.Clear;
FreeAndNil(lstPkBill);
```

Thanks you for the help, it's appreciated!

Comment: Except that calling a **record** constructor does not allocate the record on the heap, like a **class** constructor does.  This code is putting **stack-based** record instances in the `TList`.  There is nothing to deallocate.

Comment: Your code only compiles on 32 bit platforms, because it relies on the fact that `SizeOf(TPkBill) = 4`. I bet you did not realise that.

Comment: Record constructors are the work of Satan and should never ever be used. They make you think you've allocated something on the heap, or need to call `Free`. Pretend you have never heard of them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't even know what is a 32 bit platform, but I will look it up, thanks!

At TLama thank you for your proposition, but I tried RemyL. answer and it worked. But I bet it could have done the same!

Comment: If you can use generics you should. Your code will be way simpler, and safer. Less prone to leaking. Remy answer is excellent, and direct, but it's probably not the best solution to your underlying problem.

Comment: FWIW, the use of FreeAndNil is, once again, a sure sign that the author is insecure about memory management.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: "*If you can use generics you should*" - I would not go as far as saying "should". Generics have their purposes, but the current implementation is bloated and inefficient and a constant source of complaints. `TList<TPkBill>` is just a wrapper for `array of TPkBill`, which does not support efficient inserts, so it will reallocate the entire list of records on every `Add()` unless you set the `TList<TPkBill>.Capacity` property to `lvBill.SelCount` before populating the list, at least.

Comment: @Remy I agree that the current implementation fails to remove duplicate functions in instantiated types, leading to larger executable sizes. How big a problem that is, especially for a beginner, is moot. Choosing language features that emphasise type safety and avoiding typecasts is surely more productive for a beginner. As far as bloat goes, the biggest culprit, for typical programs, is new style RTTI in the library. One would have to have very extreme use of generics to out strip that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined a record with a constructor.  Calling a record constructor does not allocate memory on the heap, like a class constructor does.  Your `oPkBill` variable exists on the stack.  Calling `oPkBill := TPkBill.Create(...)` merely populates the members of that variable. You are then type-casting that entire variable (which only contains one Integer member) into a `TObject` pointer.  You are not actually allocating any memory on the heap for the list item, so there is no need to free them.

I suspect what you were actually trying to do is something more like this:

```
type
  PPkBill = ^TPkBill;
  TPkBill = record
    PkBill: integer;
    Constructor Create(c_PkBill: integer);
  end;

constructor TPkBill.Create(c_PkBill: integer);
begin
  PkBill := c_PkBill;
end;

procedure TfrmProject.lvBillDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var   
  i: Integer;
  item: TListItem;
  oPkBill: PPkBill;
  lstPkBill: TList;
begin
  if lvBill.ItemIndex = -1 then Exit;

  //an item is selected in lv

  lstPkBill := TList.Create;
  try
    //Loop through all items and get selected items
    for i := 0 to lvBill.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin
      item := lvBill.Items.Item[i];
      if item.Selected then
      begin
        //create new item
        New(oPkBill);
        try
          oPkBill^ := TPkBill.Create(StrToInt(lvBill.Items[i].Caption));
          //add it to a list
          lstPkBill.Add(oPkBill);
        except
          Dispose(oPkBill);
          raise;
        end;
      end;
    end;

    //Now we have a list ok pkBill
    if (lstPkBill.Count > 1) then
    begin
      //other stuff I do
    end;
  finally
    for i := 0 to lstPkBill.Count - 1 do
      Dispose(PPkBill(lstPkBill[i]));
    lstPkBill.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks you for your quick response! It work really well with `  PPkBill = ^TPkBill;` I understand that I didn't choose the best technique with the explanations. I'm still a bit confuse of how to handle things sometimes so I love to have answers coming from experienced programmers =) Thanks again for the clarity!

Comment: Yes, it works well, but do you actually understand why and why you were lucky that your code worked at all?

Comment: Try adding some additional record members to the original code and watch it fail, then you should understand why my approach works.